# Cloudflare identifying CURL

Tags: firefox, curl, cloudflare

So I'm trying to create some scripts that have to run on a particular site protected by CloudFlare. I am getting one odd situation though:

- Whenever I send a cURL request with the command line to that particular website (just a GET request), it reports a `503`.
- When I do the same request with a Firefox RESTED client, it reports a `200`. - Running it in my browser executes the javascript protection as expected (so a `200` as well)

What can possibly be the trick to identifying a CURL vs a Firefox RESTED client-request, that both seem to do the exact same thing?
I'm using:

- same IP
- same `User-Agent` (in fact I tried mocking over 7 headers that my regular browser sends too, including `Accept-Language` `Accept-Encoding` and more)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when using the RESTED Firefox add-on, it uses all cookies that are currently in your firefox browser as well. One of these cookies identified my RESTED client as being valid